# Which users are currently connected to an Openfire Jabber server?

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I have got an Openfire Jabber server with in excess of 75,000 users listed.  Of those, 150 or more can be online at any one time.

Is there anywhere that I can collect the JIDs (usernames) of the currently logged in users? I have full database access to the underlying data, but the server does not appear to write the current status back to the DB.  Because of the number of users, rosters are not being used.

A very useful set of data being returned would be from a simple (password protected) webpage with one JID per line, optionally with the login time, and maybe also the last time that account performed an action [like send a message].  The latter two are not as essential, but would be useful if the data is available, as well as any other information that was available regarding the user session.

Answer (score 2):

dont know if this will help but I ran into it looking for similar functionality. As defined in XEP-0045 http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#disco-roominfo :

> An implementation MAY return a list of existing occupants if that information is publicly
>   available, or return no list at all if this information is kept private. Implementations 
>   and deployments are advised to turn off such information sharing by default.

So you would need to ensure it works as advertised on Openfire (all xmpp servers ive come across have a bug or two in them), and I imagine you would need to code some logic to get the results.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect answer, but the query you want is probably embedded in the session-summary.jsp page.  I got to it on a locally hosted server at http://localhost:9090/session-summary.jsp.  What I don't know is if that is then stored in the database where it is query-able, or if it is stored internally to the client.  The latter is more likely.

The data that page displays is Name, Resource, Status, Presence, Priority, Client IP, and Close Connection.

Comment: That would be a lot of pages to scrape though. I'm hoping for some DB-access, or maybe connection to the server to retrieve a big list of currently logged in JIDs, maybe with the additional info as above.